# Why does this simple JavaScript+Ajax+php code not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to ajax, I am trying to send the html page data to php without reloading the current page. When I click on submit button it just blink "processing..."

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "simple.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>`
```

**Php file**

```
<?php 
echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';
?>
```

**Edit 1**

I added alert message in onreadystatechange. It showing three alert messages 2,3,4 respectively.

```
alert(hr.readyState);
```

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean? Console errors? PHP Error messages? - also you have a `</script>` floating around after `<head>`

Comment: Try to `alert()`/`console.debug()` the `hr.readyState` and `hr.status` in your `onreadystatechange` function (above the if) and see what the output is.

Comment: `</script>` i can see this closing first element in the head.

Comment: Hi @lvar , I added alert message {alert(hr.readyState);} in onreadystatechange. It showing three alert messages 2,3,4 respectively.

Comment: @Sparta Alright, but I think that the `hr.status` has more important information. Try to output that as well.

Comment: @lvar hr.status is showing 200 all three times.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things i can see:

1. `</script>` a closing of the script which doesn't have any opening tag in the head.
2. The variable `vars` doesn't create a query string as it is missing a `?`.

---

So, the complete changes would be:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_post(){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "simple.php";
        var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
        var vars = "?firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
        //----------^---put this at start.
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        hr.send(vars);
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

Or you can send it as:

```
hr.send({ firstname:fn, lastname:ln });
```

Comment: But the it has an opening tag?! Right after `<head>` am I wrong?

Comment: @Sparta how you are testing  this ajax. On your local server or file system.

Comment: @Jai file system

Comment: @Sparta what!!! No way. Ajax should be used on webserver only either local or other servers.

Comment: @Sparta You should also say PHP just works on a webserver too :D